# How to sort a HashMap by it amount of value in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have declared a HashMap like this:

```
Map<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

It has an output like this:

`{64=[61, 68, 77], 65=[63, 66, 66, 70], 66=[69, 75, 2], 2=[4], 67=[65, 77], 4=[2]}`

How do I count an value amount of its key?

So for 64 will be 3, 65 will be 4 and 66 will be 3

And then get a keys which has top 3 value amount
So the output in this case be like `65 64 66`

Comment: Please explain a little better what you are trying to do, because I can't understand what you need. Why will 64 be 3 and 65 be 3?

Comment: why output for 65 is 3? There are 4 elements for 65 65=[63, 66, 66, 70].

Comment: You mean the number of DISTINCT elements in the list?

Comment: That doesn't make sense either maurice as 66 will be 2. We have to go further!

Comment: @MauricePerry if that was the case 66 wouldn't be 2 ...

Comment: No; I don't get it

Comment: It's my mistake, I'm so sorry. I'm just edit it.

Comment: Can you explain then why 66 is still 2?

Comment: @Isafe how about 66?

Comment: What I want is to sort a HashMap by number of elements of its key.

Comment: there's no sorting in a HashMap, read the doc

Comment: `List<Integer> result = numbers.entrySet().stream().map((k,l) -> new AbstractMap.Entry<>(k,l.size())).sort((a,b) -> Integer.compare(b.getValue(), a.getValue())).limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList(e -> e.getKey()));`

Comment: Make a new hashmap, go through the current one, count the length of the arraylist for each value. Find the highest one, save it in your new hashmap and remove it from the old. Rinse repeat until your current hashmap is empty.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera as I had read this would be work, But it has some error in syntax which I can't fix it.

Comment: Let me assume that all numbers are paired. For example in this case will be (64,61) , (64,68) ,(64,77). How do I count how many pairs are occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> numbers = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
numbers.put(64, Arrays.asList(61, 68, 77));
numbers.put(65, Arrays.asList(63, 66, 66, 70));
numbers.put(66, Arrays.asList(69, 75, 2));
numbers.put(67, Arrays.asList(65, 77));
numbers.put(2, Arrays.asList(4));
numbers.put(4, Arrays.asList(2));

List<Integer> topValues = numbers.entrySet().stream()
       .collect(
               Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    entry -> entry.getValue().size()
                ) // get a map where key=original key and value list size
       )  // {64=3, 65=4, 2=1, 66=3, 67=2, 4=1}
       .entrySet()
       .stream() // sort map by value - list size
       .sorted( Map.Entry.<Integer,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
       .limit(3) // get top 3 
       .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(topValues); // [65, 64, 66]
```

As a first step we transform out map `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> numbers` to a new temporary map `Map<Integer,Integer>` where a key is key from original map, and a value is a list size.  So the original map 
`{64=[61, 68, 77], 65=[63, 66, 66, 70], 66=[69, 75, 2], 2=[4], 67=[65, 77], 4=[2]}` will became `{64=3, 65=4, 2=1, 66=3, 67=2, 4=1}` Then we will sort temporary map in descending order, and will get top 3 elements. As final step we will get keys of the top 3, and add them to topValues list.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First: you cannot sort a HashMap, it's unsorted by nature and for performance reasons, you should use a LinkedHashMap for that, here's a java8 example which should solve your problem:

```
class SortALinkedHashMapByTheSizeOfItsContainedArrayList {
LinkedHashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> numbers = new LinkedHashMap<>();

 void sortTheMap(){
    numbers.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .forEach(entry -> entry.getValue().size() );

 }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse said it have an error : The method sorted(Comparator<? super Map.Entry<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>>) in the type Stream<Map.Entry<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>> is not applicable for the arguments (Comparator<Map.Entry<Object,Comparable<? super Comparable<? super V>>>>) what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reverse-ordered `TreeMap` to order your `Map`'s keys according to their value's size:

```
    SortedMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> sizes = new TreeMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (Integer key : numbers.keySet()) {
        int size = numbers.get(key).size();
        if (sizes.get(size) == null) {
            sizes.put(size, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
        sizes.get(size).add(key);
    }
    System.out.println(sizes.values());
```

This will print:

```
[[65], [64, 66], [67], [2, 4]]
```

If you want to remove the `[]`, you can loop over `sizes.values()` and print only the contents of each contained list, or just print `sizes.values().toString().replace("[","").replace("]",""))` to remove them from the printed string.

Answer (score -1):

Java 8 Version. This will sort according to the value in ascending order; for descending order, it is just possible to uncomment the call to Collections.reverseOrder().

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(/*Collections.reverseOrder()*/))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, 
                Map.Entry::getValue, 
                (e1, e2) -> e1, 
                LinkedHashMap::new
              ));
}
```

Comment: They don't want to sort by value, they want to sort by value's size.

Comment: I think this falls under the category of "not playing to your audience". You've used generics, streams, method references and lambdas. This is only going to confuse the hell out of him.

Answer (score -1):

Iterrate Map and get Key after that get value based on key those return list and take list size and hold in new map if iteration done after that iterated your new map.